# Outward buffering

Tags: geometry

I get the ConvexHull of a set of polygons using ST_UNION and ST_CONVEXHULL functions using PostGIS. I want to know how to create an outward buffer of the created convexhull in PostGIS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ST_ConvexHull() returns a Polygon. Using ST_Buffer() on the result will create an "outward" buffer.

```
SELECT ST_As_Text(ST_Buffer(ST_ConvexHull(ST_Union(the_geom)), 1)) FROM building_poly;
```

Comment: I used this query but it asks for some casting: SELECT ST_As_Text (ST_Buffer (foo, 1)) from
(select (ST_ConvexHull(ST_Union(the_geom))) from building_poly) As foo;

Comment: @Sanjeewa Welcome to our site!  The best ways to indicate a useful answer are to vote it up and to accept it.  That helps future users find it so they too can benefit from the question you have asked here.